# inputViewController of superview gets called when tapped on subview(UITextView)

Tags: ios, uiview, custom-keyboard, uiresponder, uiinputviewcontroller

I have `UIView Subclass` to which I have added a `UITextField`. I have set this view as my Viewcontroller's top view.
In the `UIViewSubclass`, I have overridden `inputViewController` getter to provide a custom keyboard.

When I am selecting the `UITextField`, I would assume the `becomeFirstResponder` of `UITextField` is called and I would see the keyboard associated with it. 
However, Apart from this, `inputViewController` method on my `UIView Subclass` also is getting called causing both the textfield's and the UIView's input view getting shown one on top of another. I also do not see `canBecomeFirstResponder` or `becomeFirstResponder` getting called on my `UIView's subclass`. Only `inputViewController` method is called and the custom keyboard shows up.

Could anyone help me understand why `inputViewController` is getting called on my `UIView's subclass` even when it is not becoming first responder.

**UPDATE**
From apple documentation - 
"An input view is a substitute for system keyboards that is assigned to the inputView property of a text view or a custom view. When there are input views, UIKit might swap out the keyboard even when a text object is first responder, and it might show a keyboard-like input view on the developer's behalf for non-text objects."

So if I understood this correctly, it does make sense for UIResponder to call inputViewController on my UIView subclass but it should ideally have swapped out the textfields keyboard with the inputViewController? Clearly that is not happening here.

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UIView subclass specifically to override inputViewController? You may try instead to not do that, but subclass UITextField instead, and then override inputViewController in your UITextField subclass.

Comment: I need my UIView to become first responder sometimes and have its own custom keyboard when it becomes first responder. I can't achieve this by subclassing UITextfield.